# Portlet content is not shown in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

I've recently started working with portlets, and trying to have experience with several portal engines. I have a basic hello world portlet (extending GenericPortlet and basically doing the same as in all tutorials) that works perfectly with Pluto 2.

I deployed the same portlet to Liferay 6.0, and added it to a page in the portal. Strangely, the portlet frame appears without any content. According to the logs, the portlet init() is called, but doView() is not, thus there's no portlet content in the resulted HTML page.

My question is: should the same portlet work out of the box with Liferay, too? If not, what non-standard descriptors are mandatory for deploying a portlet to Liferay? If yes, what may be the problem? I've seen portlet content height issues mentioned in some forums, but this may not be the problem: the content is not hidden, it's not generated at all.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the portlet somehow, so that we can see the files in it?

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to recheck my files to paste them, so I could find the problem. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While checking the relevant file contents to paste here as asked, I realized that my web.xml is empty (as it should be according to Liferay tutorials), but a maven plugin generates pluto-specific invoker definitions into it as defined in my pom.xml. As a result, the generated pluto-specific PlutoInvoker mappings screwed it all up. So it was solved easily, thanks for reading the question though.